# FAIL - Application at context path /HelloWorldStruts2 could not be started

Tags: java, struts2

it is my first struts2 app i try,
and the apache server manager has this error when i start the webapp

FAIL - Application at context path /HelloWorldStruts2 could not be started

the code is typically from this link
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_examples.htm

but i changed the filter-class in the web.xml to the new filter (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter)

and i don't know what is the problem with my app

Comment: is there any exception?

Comment: there isn't any exception,

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial? If yes, then there should be an image at the end showing how it works.

Comment: There's nothing here we can use to diagnose the issue.